# Call to specific class from JAR file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classloader

I want to call a Class A from JAR-1. But I have same Class in JAR-2 hence my app is calling Class A from JAR-2.

All the packages are same in both the JARs. For Eg,
`com.package.classes.A` in JAR-1 and `com.package.classes.A` in JAR-2

I want my app to call A from JAR-1.

I am using IntelliJ.(If this information helps)

Comment: this is not possible . To avoid this only we have package structure . Same package , same class name and different content of files , then its wrong . Can you provide if possible which jar you are trying to import and some examples

Comment: Sounds like a class loader issue. Sometimes alphabetizing your jars will give precedence to a jar with a name that comes before another. You could try naming your "JAR-1" file to be alphabetically before the "JAR-2" file.